# Interpolate is not function - Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-reanimated

Running my project after importing drawer navigation shows this error...

```
AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:

TypeError:  interpolate is not a function. (In 'interpolate(this.progress, {
            inputRange: [PROGRESS_EPSILON, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 1]
             })', 'interpolate' is undefined)
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
       at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
       at node_modules\expo-app-loading\build\AppLoading.js:11:12 in 
       startLoadingAppResourcesAsync._catch$argument_0
       at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in 
       tryCallOne
       at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in 
       setImmediate$argument_0
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in 
      _callImmediatesPass
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in 
      __callImmediates
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in 
      __guard$argument_0
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
       at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in 
      flushedQueue
       at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
       at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

even after installing reanimated version 1 it showing different error rather than this.

Comment: are you sure that you followed react navigation installation step by step? the above error maybe some lack of library come along with react navigation

Comment: are you using react-native version 0.60.0 or above?
do you use linking after installation ?

Comment: read this : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7504

Comment: I had the same isue its an dependency isue

Answer (score 2):

As TERMINATOR stated it is a dependency issue. Use the link he provided or follow this [link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9665#issuecomment-875813983) to another thread but with a different solution.

This answer says to `npm uninstall react-native-reanimated` then to `npm install react-native-reanimated@2.1.0`. However I had to use `npm install --force react-native-reanimated@2.1.0` to get it to install properly on my machine.